# Apply all formatting/column hide/ column width/ from one excel sheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have around 80 excel files that i have to work on and print. I have one file in which I have setup the proper format, what columns to hide what to show, what would be the column width and everything i order for proper print format. now, Instead of having to open all 81 files one by one and setting up all of those files one by one, I wish to apply the same formatting I have done in one file, to all the 80 files. I wish to apply:

1. The same column width
2. The same column Height
3. The same columns to show
4. The same columns to hide

I have used format painter but that doesn't fulfill any of the above requirements, Anything I can workaround with?

Answer (score 1):

Select all populated columns in the source sheet and copy.

Select the same number of columns in the target sheet and use Paste Special > Formats.

Do the same for rows, i.e. copy all populated rows, select the same number of rows in the target sheet and paste special > Formats

If you start the macro recorder before you do that, you'll get some code that could be easily applied to any sheet with the push of a button, but that would be another question.

Comment: Yes but that doesnt hide/unhide columns.

Comment: It does for me.